# Excel (2013) VBA – add custom properties to worksheets

Tags: excel, class, inheritance, vba

I am trying to create custom properties in a worksheet that the user can’t see.  My reasons are the following:

- avoid the `CustomProperties` collection (no direct access),
- avoid using global variables (get dropped randomly on workbook save), or
- using specific named cells on the worksheet as retrieving and inserting the values seem slow.

The code below seems to work, and I can work with all needed worksheet properties and methods of the created `sht` object. The downside is the loss of intellisense, which is not a problem for me.

Although this seems to work, my code now appears to randomly go unstable, and I can’t find any direct cause, other than the fact that I may have violated something.

I currently have 7 custom properties each in 5 worksheets.

Here is a code sample in the worksheet (at top):

```
Private pPassword As String
Public Property Get Password() As String
    Password = pPassword
End Property
Public Property Let Password(Value As String)
    pPassword = Value
End Property
```

And here is a code sample in a module:

```
Sub doSomething(currentSheetName as string)
    Dim Password as String
    Dim sht as object
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheetName)

    Blahblahblah code

    Password = sht.password

    Blahblahblah code

End sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly go unstable"?  The Intellisense and slowness is due to your calls being late bound.  If you want them to be early bound, declare them as interface members.

Comment: "randomly go unstable" means I get "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" crashes periodically for no apparent reason. I previously attempted to use early binding (Dim sht as worksheet) but was not able to return the custom properties.  I'm not sure what you mean by "declare them as interface members"?  Please explain.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from iled, I decided to create a blank worksheet, rename it to shtProperties, and add custom properties and methods to it. I can now use intellisense and change/retrieve properities from anywhere in the project. (example:  shtProperties.Password = myPassword). When each sheet is activated, I simply clear out the custom properties of shtProperties, and reset to new properties of the activesheet. No more crashes.  Thanks iled for the suggestion.